# CSS behaving strangely

Tags: html, css

The moment I place div2 within div1, div1 just drops by some random degree. Not sure what's going on here since I just placed div3 within div1 and it's working just fine.

```css
.propertyOverview {
    height: 430px;
    width: 357px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

.propertyImage {
    height: 260px;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #a29c9c;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-left: -15px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="container propertyOverview">
    <div class="propertyImage"></div>
    <div>
        Sample text
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screen shot of what I'm looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsiqn.png)

Comment: Your html code is not proper. Also style is missing class/selector name and starting bracket.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies, I updated the selector, it somehow didn't copy over

Comment: here's the codepen https://codepen.io/insivika/pen/OzNYrx

Comment: Boxes not aligned horizontally. Is that your problem?

Comment: yes sir, they are fine until I add :

Comment: <div>
                 Sample text
             </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align:top` for `inline-block` element, because the default alignment is baseline. It will resolve the issue.

```
.propertyOverview {
   height: 430px;
   width: 357px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   background-color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align:top; /* Added this one for alignment */
   border: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
.propertyOverview{
    height: 430px;
   width: 357px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   background-color: white;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   border: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.propertyImage {
   height: 260px;
   width: 357px;
   background-color: #a29c9c;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
   margin-left:0;    
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jungrupak/ptqbbugw/